# How to keep the value for a vector in Julia

Tags: julia

I have two vectors `vector1` and `vector2` in Julia. Suppose `vector1 = zeros(3)`. I set `vector2 = vector1`. Then I let `vector2[1] = 1`. `vector2` will be `[1, 0, 0]`. However, vector1 will also be `[1, 0, 0]` automatically. I want to keep vector1 as `[0, 0, 0]`.

In other words, after running

```
vector1 = zeros(3)
vector2 = vector1
vector2[1] = 1
```

I want `vector1` still be `zeros(3)`. Is there an easy way for me to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have Julia installed so I can't check this but here's how I'd do this in Python, adapted for Julia syntax. Can you confirm this works?

```
vector1 = zeros(3)
vector2 = copy(vector1)
vector2[1] = 1
```

After a bit more reading, depending on what's in your array you might want to consider `deepcopy` instead of `copy`.

Comment: Awesome, glad to help. Also just posted an update that you might want to consider `deepcopy` instead of `copy`, depending on what's in your array.